# Adding Routes to ExpressJS App from Modules

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Trying to figure out how routing middleware works on ExpressJS.

What I am trying to solve is:
app has some basic routing in the /index.js

app will have some modules that will add its own routes and handlers (eg. hello & world)

I have added different routing options to see what works - but I have overcooked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mcnulty-7b79x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `hello` and `world` routes like this:

```js
app.use(hello());
world.setup(app);
```

For some reason, the `connect-history-api-fallback` module will cause to `nothing matched` route.

If you comment the code use `history` middleware:

```js
// app.use(history());
```

Now, you can access the `hello` route via `https://ncpt4.sse.codesandbox.io/hello` and access the `world` route via `https://ncpt4.sse.codesandbox.io/world`.

example link: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-worker-ncpt4